# Log User in programatically for Magento 2 (via Contoller)

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, controllers, login, customer-session

I have a process in Magento 1 to log user in using the below;

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

$email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
$password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password'); 

//log user in
$session->login($email, $password);

//then check session/is logged in
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

  //successfully logged in user

}
```

I wish to process the same in Magento 2, but unsure if $session->login() can be executed or is there another function in:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

//or Magento equivalent for below;
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below solution for when both email & password are passed for validation/session authentication ...

Uses `EncryptorInterface` to validate passed password against users password hash

```
$this->_encryptor->validateHash($password, $sessionPasswordHash);
```

Full code below, but excludes additional checks that user is infact logged in after `$this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)` or before processing request checks `if (!empty($email) && !empty($password)){ ... }`

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Controller\Api;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Auth extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

protected $jsonResultFactory;
protected $_customer;
protected $_customerSession;

protected $_encryptor;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonResultFactory,,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor
) {

    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_encryptor = $encryptor;

    parent::__construct($context);        
    $this->jsonResultFactory = $jsonResultFactory;

}

public function execute()
{
    $jsonResultArray = array();


    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
    $password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password'); 

    if (!empty($email) && !empty($password)){

                $customer = $this->_customer->loadByEmail($email);

                $sessionEmail = $customer->getEmail();
                $sessionPasswordHash = $customer->getPasswordHash();

                if($sessionEmail == $email && $this->_encryptor->validateHash($password, $sessionPasswordHash)){

                    $logUserIn = $this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

                    if($logUserIn){

                        $jsonResultArray['result'] = 'success';
                        $jsonResultArray['message'] = 'Successfully API Authenticated';


                    }else{


                        $jsonResultArray['result'] = 'error';
                        $jsonResultArray['message'] = 'Error with API Authentication';
                        $jsonResultArray['error'] = 'Error logging User In';

                    }

                }else{

                    $jsonResultArray['result'] = 'error';
                    $jsonResultArray['message'] = 'Error with Authentication';
                    $jsonResultArray['error'] = 'Error logging User In';

                }


            }else{

        $jsonResultArray['result'] = 'error';
        $jsonResultArray['message'] = 'Error Authenticating';

    }

    $result = $this->jsonResultFactory->create();
    $result->setHttpResponseCode(200);
    $result->setData($jsonResultArray);

    return $result;

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
// Load customer
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load(2); //2 is Customer ID

// Load customer session
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo "Customer Logged in";
}else{
    echo "customer is Not Logged in";
}
```

Comment: Although not entirely what I was after, pointed me in the right direction and answers the question. thank you +1